# Accessing protocol property in Swift class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I am trying to use a protocol to pass an array from one class to another.

```
protocol PinsArray {
var dataArray: [LocationPost] {get set}
}
```

When I am trying to create a delegate in class, which should receive it does not work. I cannot access the property

```
var delegate = PinsArray.self
```

Like this:

```
delegate.dataArray
```

It says that "instance member 'dataArray' cannot be used on type PinArray"

So what do I do wrong?

Comment: please show a little bit more code, where is `var delegate = PinsArray.self` located, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: The `PinsArray` protocol defines an instance method, `PinsArray.self` returns the protocol type `PinsArray`, so `delegate.dataArray` is a call to a missing type method `dataArray`, not the instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the **type** of `PinsArray` to `delegate` instead of assigning an **instance** of a class that conforms `PinsArray`. You would need to implement an a class that conforms to `PinsArray` and assign an instance of that class to delegate. See the following example:

```
class SomeClass: PinsArray {
    var dataArray: [LocationPost]
    // ...
}
```

You would use the class above to create an instance of an object that conforms to `PinsArray`.

```
var delegate = SomeClass()
```

Then you could use:

```
delegate.dataArray
```

Comment: you cannot instantiate protocols.

Comment: Good catch. You are correct. I will update my example.

Answer (score 0):

I declared the delegate with a typo, it should be like this:

```
var delegate: PinsArray?
```