# Changing a delegate's property through protocol

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, delegates, protocols

I have `controllingView`, that needs to change a property in  `presentingView`. They are both in the same `ViewController`.

I can let them communicate by making `presentingView` delegate of `controllingView`. But it would be far more elegant and flexible, if I could just change the property directly (*since
I need to change the `presentingView`'s property's property actually*)

I have seen it done in this question: [Accessing protocol property in Swift class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730672/accessing-protocol-property-in-swift-class). 
But in `controllingView`, calling `delegate.propertyINeedToChange` is `nil`.
**How do I change a delegate's property from the delegating object?**

Here is the code:

```
class MainViewController : UIViewController {

    var controllingView = ControllingView()
    let presentingView = PresentingView()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(controllingView)
        view.addSubview(presentingView)

        self.view = view
        controllingView.delegate = presentingView
    }
}


class ControllingView: UIView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //ControlsView Setup
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        setupViews()
    }

    let testSLDR = UISlider()

    var delegate: ControlsViewDelegate?

    func setupViews() {
        self.addSubview(testSLDR)
        testSLDR.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testSLDRchanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func testSLDRchanged() {
        delegate?.button?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}

class PresentingView: UIView, ControlsViewDelegate {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let button = Button()
        self.addSubview(button)

    }

    var button: Button?

}

protocol ControlsViewDelegate {
    var button: Button? { get set }
}


class Button: UIButton { ... }
```

Comment: Which property are you talking about?

Comment: An instance property of presentingView (the delegate)

Comment: Do you wanted to do your custom present?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: If they are both in the same view controller, why do you need to even use delegates?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Code has been added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the views are initialized in the same view controller you don't need protocol / delegate

- Delete the protocol and the associated code
- In `ControllingView` declare a weak `Button` property

  ```
  weak var presentingButton : Button?
  ```
- Replace the line to set the delegate with a line to assign the button of `PresentingView` to the `presentingButton` property

  <strike>`controllingView.delegate = presentingView`</strike>

  ```
  controllingView.presentingButton = presentingView.button
  ```
- In the action change the color

  ```
  @objc func testSLDRchanged() {
      presentingButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much. Initially I could not get this to work. But my mistake was redeclaring `Button` in `controllingView`'s initializer. Thus leaving it's `button` property nil